# how to make user input int null value c#

Tags: c#, null, integer

I'm trying to make a program that takes a number and print it on screen but if the user press enter the code ask the user to enter the number again but instead it shows me a exception

```
Enter_No:
                 Console.WriteLine("enter number");
                 int? n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                 if (n == (int?)null)
                 {
                     goto Enter_No;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(n);
                 }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting and what line does it say the exception occurs on? You need to examine that information.

Comment: int? n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: input string was not in correct format

Comment: The error is because you are trying to parse an empty string as a number. Never assume that user input data are clean.
Also, for the `int?` type (and other value-types (e.g. structs)) you should do `x.HasValue` instead of comparing with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim's solution is wonderfully compact. Here's why your attempt failed.

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.7.2), Convert.ToInt32() throws a FormatException if:

> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

The preferred approach is `int.TryParse()`, as it returns false if it's unable to parse the integer rather than throwing an exception.

While the `goto` keyword is supported in C#, there are few or no situations (depending on who you ask) where it's the best option for flow control. Tim's `while` loop is an excellent approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use `int.TryParse`:

```
int? num = null;
while(!num.HasValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer:");
    num = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int i) ? i : new int?();
}

Console.WriteLine("Entered integer: " + num.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use Go To:

Second: Inspect your data and use tryparse:

```
        bool success = false;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter number");
            var n = Console.ReadLine();
            if (n == null)
            {
                // goto Enter_No;
            }
            else
            {
                int typedNum;
                success = int.TryParse(n, out typedNum);
                Console.WriteLine(typedNum);                    
            }
        } while (!success);
```